# DDOS attack on cloudflare attached server

Tags: central-processing-unit, ddos, cloudflare, ufw

So I have like 4 Digital Ocean droplets and they all are attached to DNS through cloudflare. The problem is they all are being attackers in different times of month by millions of IPs and some of them are stopped by cloudflare but some pass through my site. The CPU is pegged at 100% and the most used process is mysqlnd (When the server is not under attack the mysqlnd usage is pretty normal).
I even added the firewall protection from Digital ocean and allowed a few ports only. But the attackers attack on random links like some image on site or some URLs. I have also activated automatic captcha so that suspicious users will be shown capctha from Cloudflare.

I have also tried UFW but still issues are still there.
Help me resolve this issue it's been a headache for me for quite a while.

Comment: How are you sure that this is an attack? Just because MySQL spikes doesn't mean it's an attack. Is your `netstat` showing huge amounts of connections? What about the logs? If you're truly under a DOS attack, there's nothing you can do **locally**, you would need to work with the upstream provider to start blocking IP's and redirecting traffic.

Comment: I'm sure it's an attack because when the cloudflare started showing me millions of attacks in 24 hours the spike on Digital oceans shows that for last 24 hours the CPU was at 100% and once the attacks stop it comes down

Comment: Ok. Well, if it's an attack, you should work with CloudFlare to help mitigate the traffic being sent to your site. Alternatively, scale up and load balance to soak the hit.